# Finding a pattern among numbers using numpy

Tags: pandas, numpy

I am trying to match two datasets.  In the image below, the first data set is matched to the second dataset based on the column "Rounded Diff".  If the number is within 1, then it's a match. The ones in red, do not match, so the first dataset would have to continue to go down (an undetermined number of records) the second dataset until there is another matching set of numbers.  I am currently doing this by looping through a numpy array.  I was wondering if I could use anything else to get the same result.

The Arrays for the images below are:

```
firstdataset =np.array([[6.01,1.17,1],[7.18,17.6,18],[24.78,14.8,15],[39.58,12.77,13],[52.35,13.02,13],[65.37,12.89,13],[78.26,43.75,44],[122.01,44.07,44],[166.08,8.5,9],[174.58,4.199,4],[178.78,9.56,10],[188.35,9.12,9],[197.47,20.06,20],[217.53,19.97,20],[237.5,2.02,2],[239.52,37.96,38],[277.48,40.12,40],[317.6,23.4,23],[341,5.959,6],[346.96,2.340,2],[349.3,1.979,2],[351.28,8.530,9],[359.81,16.54,17],[376.35,2.21997,2],[378.57,4.8601,5]])



seconddataset =np.array([[1.48,4.45,4],[5.93,1.22,1],[7.15,17.3,17],[24.45,14.82,15],[39.27,12.8,13],[52.07,12.98,13],[65.05,12.98,13],[78.03,43.67,44],[121.7,44.01,44],[165.71,8.5,9],[174.21,4.1699,4],[178.38,9.5099,10],[187.89,9.09,9],[196.98,1.08,1],[198.06,3.020,3],[201.08,0.889,1],[201.97,0.93,1],[202.9,2.109,2],[205.01,2.22,2],[207.23,2.1,2],[209.33,1.16,1],[210.49,3.2,3],[213.7,1,1],[214.7,2.4202,2],[217.12,19.82,20],[236.94,1.949,2],[238.89,37.94,38],[276.83,40,40],[316.83,23.35,23],[340.18,5.94,6],[346.13,2.37,2],[348.5,1.930,2],[350.43,8.71,9],[359.15,16.67,17],[375.82,2.18,2],[378,4.839,5]])
```

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Comment: Add your data as text. [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). It is likely the question will be down-voted. You are discouraging assistance because no one wants to retype your data or code, and screenshots are often illegible.

Comment: sorry about that, i added the numpy arrays.  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can you difflib's [`Sequencematcher`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/difflib.html#sequencematcher-objects):

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
sm = SequenceMatcher(None, firstdataset[:,2], seconddataset[:,2])
mb = sm.get_matching_blocks()
#[Match(a=0, b=1, size=1), Match(a=2, b=3, size=10), Match(a=13, b=24, size=12), Match(a=25, b=36, size=0)]
```

The matching sequences themselves can be found by:

```
for b in mb[:-1]:
    print(firstdataset[b.a:b.a+b.size, 2])
```

Result:

```
[1.]
[15. 13. 13. 13. 44. 44.  9.  4. 10.  9.]
[20.  2. 38. 40. 23.  6.  2.  2.  9. 17.  2.  5.]
```

(there's an error in your green coloring in the example: the second line of the first dataset differs from the third line of the second dataset)

Comment: thank you for your response, I will try it.  also, if first data set is within 1 of the second dataset it is still a match.  So 18 and 17 would still match.

Comment: Oh sorry, I overlooked that. In this case my solution won't work, it only finds exact matches.